# inserting multiple rows in mysql from json string/array using php?

Tags: php, mysql, json

"i am trying to develop an script which allows me to insert multiple rows from an jsonarray in mysql database, but upon testing only one rows is being inserted and here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die('Unable to Connect');
     if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
     {
         $jsonData=file_get_contents("sampledata.json");
         $jsonString=json_decode($jsonData,true);
         foreach($jsonString['Order Summary'] as $cart)
         {
             $name=$cart['ProductName'];
             $price=$cart['ProductPrice'];
             $quantity=$cart['ProductQuantity'];
             $cost=$cart['ProductCost'];
             $seller=$cart['SellerId'];
             $stmt=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO sProducts(Name,Price,Quantity,Cost,Sellerid)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
             $stmt->bind_param("sssss",$name,$price,$quantity,$cost,$seller);
             if($stmt->execute())
              return json_encode("data inserted");
            return json_encode("error");     
         } 
     }
```

can anyone tell me where is the mistake or could guide me into this direction ?

Comment: Why did you not debug it step by step?

Comment: `return ...` ? Is your code block inside any function?

Comment: When you return, the script stops. So, it'll only insert the first row. Then, you don't need to prepare the query for each iteration - prepare it once, before you start looping.

Answer (score 1):

For one, you are reutrning in the first iteration of the loop - which means that the script stops. `return` should only be used to return from a function.

If you remove both `return`s, that will make the loop continue until its done.

And you should not prepare the query inside the loop, its not needed - and much more efficient to prepare it before you start looping (it can be used multiple times with different values when you bind and execute in a loop). I've also added some spaces in the code to make it easier to read

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die('Unable to Connect');
$msg = "data inserted";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
    $jsonData = file_get_contents("sampledata.json");
    $jsonString = json_decode($jsonData,true);
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO sProducts (Name, Price, Quantity, Cost, Sellerid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    foreach($jsonString['Order Summary'] as $cart) {
        $name = $cart['ProductName'];
        $price = $cart['ProductPrice'];
        $quantity = $cart['ProductQuantity'];
        $cost = $cart['ProductCost'];
        $seller = $cart['SellerId'];
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $name, $price, $quantity, $cost, $seller);
        if (!$stmt->execute())
            $msg = "Something went wrong";
    } 
}
return json_encode($msg);
```